# What is the difference between defining types for arrow function in these two ways?

Tags: typescript, types, arrow-functions

I'm confused about what the difference between these two the following types of a dummy arrow function. Can someone please point out the difference?

```
const hello = (i: string):string => { return "Hi, User!" }
```

and

```
const hello: string = (i: string) => { return "Hi, User!" }
```

Comment: One is valid and the other throws an error. Have you tried to compile your code first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

second function throw error!

```
[yours]
1. const hello = (i: string):string => { return "Hi, User!" } // correct

2. const hello: string = (i: string) => { return "Hi, User!" } // error
```

Because hello function type is not string.

hello function type is "(i: string) => string".

```
[correct]
const hello: (i:string) => string = (i: string) => { return "Hi, User!" }
```